# A way to push notification to desktop and mobile from a website?

Tags: 8, notifications

I'm looking for a way to push notification to desktop and mobile from a website built with D8. All modules I could find are abandoned sandbox or for D7...
If I well understood, the way to push notification to desktop are different from the one to mobile.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a ready-to-use solution, I don't think you're going to have much luck at this moment in time.

If you're willing to get your hands dirty and write some code, I would suggest looking at [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com) and its [API](https://docs.pushbullet.com). It's very easy to get started with and it can send push notifications to smartphones, web browsers and desktops (as long as they're running the requisite [app or extension](https://www.pushbullet.com/apps)).

You could incorporate something as simple as this into a custom module:

```
$title = 'Some title text';
$body = 'Some body text';

$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
$request = $client->post('https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes', array(
  'headers' => array(
    'Access-Token' => 'your_access_token_here',
  ),
  'json' => array(
    'type' => 'note',
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $body,
  ),
));
```

You're not limited to simple text notifications either; it can push links and files as well.